# Display in pdb++ not working

Tags: python, pdb

I was trying to modify pdb++ and add watch capability to it. However, I found that it was already implemented, that is, display in pdb++ does watch the variables.

I'm able to watch all the variables inside my test file (test.py) if I do

```
python pdb.py test.py
```

But, if I add the following code inside test.py (and ran it as python test.py), I'm not able to do many functions like display, sticky, etc.

```
import pdb as bp
bp.set_trace()
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb/)?

Comment: Thanks Vasiliy, looks great. But, I wanted to modify and play with pdb++.